# The rank of a map inducing a manifold

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $A\subset {\mathbb R}^n $ be open. Let $\psi\colon {\mathbb R}^m \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^n$, $m<n$, 
a smooth, injective map of maximal rank $m$. Set $Y=\psi(A)$ and $Y_{\psi}$ the corresponding manifold. 
Now assume that $Y$ is given also implicitly by $\{x\in {\mathbb R}^{n}|f(x)=0\}$ where 
$f\colon {\mathbb R}^{n} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}^{n-m}$ is a smooth map.

Is it true that in this case $f$ has a maximal rank $n-m$ at each point $x\in Y$?

If possible please kindly restrict the argument to be suitable for a graduate student that took a course in multivariate calculus but not in differential geometry/topology.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Counter example: Take $f$ as above and $g=f^2$. Then $Y=\{x|g(x)=0\}$ but $Dg(y)$ is the zero 
matrix at all points $y\in Y$.